# 'OutOfMemoryError' while adding multiple images to ImageViews inside ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, viewflipper

I have a fragment contains 6 ViewFlippers, each flipper contains at least 10 ImageViews. I tried to load all the images and put them in the ImageViews but the restricted memory didn't let me to do that. Every time I run the application this exception occurs.

when I reduce number of images my app runs, but that's not a solution.
So what's the best way for doing that?

Here what I tried so far:

```
for(int i=0; i<flippers.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(names[j], "drawable", rootView.getContext().getPackageName());
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(rootView.getContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
        flippers[i].addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

> 26546-26546/com.azad E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.azad, PID: 26546
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Did u check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)?

Comment: I think you could use some libraries which have image caching and resizing image before using it to reduce memory usage. There are many, the Android Universal Image Loader library could be a good choice for you.

Comment: you need to reduce image size(pixels), for example an Image with 1080*3000 px with "70 Kb size" , get about "50 Mb" of ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of library for resizing the image before loading

Some of the library you can use are

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

[UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

This library will help you to cache the image. And when the image is not required you can clear it from memory

Comment: +1, I used Picasso, it will only load most of the images. Now I have two ViewFlippers with empty imageViews. Why is that? Is it because of memory ?

Comment: Are you using .resize() method of Picasso while loading image?